# Button background color is repeating in the uicollectionview cell

Tags: uibutton, uicollectionviewcell, background-color

I have a like button on my cell (that has been connected to the CustomCVCell.h file) and I need to change the background of this button when it gets pressed.For that I written this code.

Collectionviewcell.h

- (IBAction)secondlikebuttn:(id)sender;

In collectionviewcell.m

```
  - (IBAction)secondlikebuttn:(id)sender {

UIButton *buttonObj = (UIButton*)sender;

[buttonObj setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like_icon_inst1_red"]
                              forState:UIControlStateNormal];

_commview.hidden=YES;
_shareview.hidden=YES;
_likeview.hidden=NO;
```

}
  when click on the button  the background image of the button at selected idexpath is changing but the problem is it is reflecting the  change in other indexpath also.

[image]

Thanks for quick responses.

Comment: @sateeshkumar  did you check the uibutton background colour property

Comment: @spynet yes I checked it the button background image is changing.

Comment: let me add the images.

Comment: hey background image / background color any one is possible can can you elaborate your issue in deeper. okay

Comment: okey I have collectionviewcell like instagram timeline,when i click like button at some indexpath the background image of the button changes,but the issues is the background images is changing for some other like buttons which is at next indexpath

Comment: for example I have 15 posts I want to like one post say its indexpath is 5 when i click the like button the background image of the like button changes at index path 5 and the background image of the like button at indexpath 7 also changing.

Comment: Every time didselect reload the data

Comment: 1.if I do that background image of current button changes or not,2.If not how to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121535/discussion-between-spynet-and-satheeshkumar-naidu).